# Variable value not gets updated if function has same name as variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I expected the answer to be "function text" as output, why the answer is 5?

```js
var alpha = 5;
function alpha(){}
console.log(alpha);
```

Comment: functions are hoisted to the top of the scope ... therefore, think of your code as having the function definition **first** - now it should make sense (why would you want such code!!!)

Comment: It is due to hosting in javascript. Regardless of where a function is placed, it is moved to the top of the scope in which it is define. If you want "function alpha" as output, declare function as function expression.